# Why doesn't PreSendRequestHeaders fire on IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, httpmodule

I've developed an HTTP module that registers an event handler for the [PreSendRequestHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders.aspx) event. Within the event handler, I want to be able to add HTTP headers to the response. The event handler is called when the application is running on my local computer, which runs Windows 7 and IIS7.5.

However, when I deploy the application on a server running Windows Server 2003 and IIS6, the event handler doesn't seem to be called at all. I've concluded this because even when the event handler is coded to throw an exception when it is called, no errors occur. I had no problems when I was instead using the [EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx) event.

Is this normal? If so, why, and what is an acceptable work-around? If not, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You must've gotten an answer by now... how did you get around this?

Comment: @dotnetguy, I can't actually remember what I was trying to use this for, but I don't remember ever finding an explanation for this.

Comment: Turns out this (obviously) work differently on IIS 6. In my Web API, I was using this event to strip the Server header from the response - it works fine on IIS 7/Win 7 but throws an exception on IIS 6 so I followed an SO discussion to check IIS version before doing the header removal. Let me know if it is of interest to you